# Create group number for contiguous runs of equal values

Tags: r, performance, loops, indexing, counting

Is there is a faster way to make a counter index than using a loop? For each contiguous run of equal values, the index should be the same. I find the looping very slow especially when the data is so big.

For illustration, here is the input and desired output

```
x <- c(2, 3, 9, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1)
```

Desired resulting counter:

```
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9)
```

Note that *non*-contiguous runs have *different* indexes. E.g. see the desired indexes of the values `2` and `4`

My inefficient code is this:

```
group[1]<-1
counter<-1
for (i in 2:n){
if (x[i]==x[i-1]){
    group[i]<-counter
}else{
    counter<-counter+1
    group[1]<-counter}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have numeric values like this, you can use `diff` and `cumsum` to add up changes in values

```
x <- c(2,3,9,2,4,4,3,4,4,5,5,5,1)
cumsum(c(1,diff(x)!=0))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 8 8 9
```

Comment: Definitely faster than my answer.  Can't assess against Arun's `data.table` answer at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Frank for that comment. I will now use MrFlick's suggestion. It seems that some installation is needed for the data.table suggestion of Arun.

Comment: Yep, if you want to try Arun's solution see this link for help on installation:  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: @Frank, pushed an even faster version of `rleid()` yesterday which is also memory efficient. Here, `diff(x)`, `c(...)`, `!=` and `cumsum()` each allocate new memory, meaning it requires ~4x the original data in space!!

Answer (score 13):

Using [`data.table`](http://r-datatable.com/Getting-started), which has the function `rleid()`:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
rleid(x)
#  [1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 8 8 9
```

Answer (score 7):

This will work with numeric of character values:

```
rep(1:length(rle(x)$values), times = rle(x)$lengths)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 8 8 9
```

You can also be a bit more efficient by calling `rle` just once (about 2x faster) and a *very* slight speed improvement can be made using `rep.int` instead of `rep`:

```
y <- rle(x)
rep.int(1:length(y$values), times = y$lengths)
```

Answer (score 3):

Above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30314858/2884859) by Jota can be further simplified to, which will be even faster

```
with(rle(x), rep(1:length(lengths), lengths))

 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 8 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you can use `consecutive_id`:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0+
consecutive_id(x)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 8 8 9
```